# How to find if image in landscape or portrait orientation in Java?

Tags: java, bufferedimage

Is there any method that shows if the image is in landscape orientation or not?
I have a file and I create a `BufferedImage`, but don't know what's the method for finding the orientation.

Comment: You have to be more specific. What kind of images are these? do they have a predefined size (width, height)? do you expect some cropping or additional white/black/transparent background additions... more info, please.

Comment: Do you have the image also as a file before? or just as BufferedImage?

Comment: i have the image as a file..and than with ImageIO i create it as BufferedImage...now if the image is not in landscape orientation i have to rotate it clockwise...i know how to rotate with affine transformation API but dont know how to check for the orientation..thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are not method but the easiest way:

```
public boolean isLandscape(BufferedImage image){
  return image.getWidth() > image.getHeight();
}
```

You could put this method to some Utils class.

Comment: what if the same image with height < width showed in landscape mode...it is actually a portrait image , but will look like a landscape image if the orientation is changed... I dont think that comparing the height and width will help...is there any other way to find the orientation(example embedded values from the image)...?

Answer (score 0):

try this ....

```
  if (image.getIconWidth() > image.getIconHeight()) 
    {  result = 0;
     } else {
    result = 1;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

What about:

```
return (bi.getHeight () < bi.getWidth ());
```